# Create a Customer User Defined function for replacing the missing rows using Mean Median Mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I tried to create a custom user defined function in python for replacing the missing values in a dataset by using Mean value,Median Value and Mode Value. But I am unable to get the required Output.

Condition:

Null values will be replaced by its Mean value when the column present in the dataset is not skewed.
Null values will be replaced by its Median value when column present in the dataset is skewed.
Null Values will be replaced by its Mode value when the column present in the dataset is a categrorical variable column.

dataframe:
[image: sample data]

[image: code]

[image: Error after removing quotes from column]

Comment: show us the dataframe, and post the code you tried as well

Comment: Could you share the output you are getting? in the secod elif condition you wrote "columns" instead of "column"and Please write "coulmn" without quotes{""}

Comment: Do not post data or code as a screenshot but rather as text in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

```
import pandas as pd

def conditional_impute(df,column_name,choice):
    try:
        if choice == 'mean':
            mean_value = df[column_name].mean()
            df[column_name].fillna(value=mean_value, inplace=True)
        elif choice == 'median':
            median_value = df[column_name].median()
            df[column_name].fillna(value=median_value, inplace=True)
        elif choice == 'mode':
            mode_value = df[column_name].mode()[0]
            df[column_name].fillna(value=mode_value, inplace=True)
    except Exception:
        print('Wrong Argument')
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,34,4],'b':[None,1,None,4]})
df = conditional_impute(df,'b','mode')
```

The output of model dataframe is,

```
    a    b
0   1  1.0
1   2  1.0
2  34  1.0
3   4  4.0
```